# onClick function does not work (not changing color of the string)

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, mouseevent

I am trying to make a dynamic function onClick which will change the color of the string, but color won't change, same function works if I call consol.log

```
const heading = document.getElementById('Hello')

function addStyleTo(node, text, color, fontSize) {
    node.textContent = text
    node.style.color = color
    node.style.textAlign = 'center' 
    node.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
    node.style.padding = '2rem' 
    node.style.fontSize = fontSize
}

setTimeout(() => {
    addStyleTo(heading, 'Hello', 'red', '3rem')
}, 1000);

heading.onclick = () => {
    if (heading.style.color === 'red') {
        heading.style.color === 'pink' 
    } else {
        heading.style.color === 'red'
}
```

Comment: The triple equals sign `===` is used when comparing variables. When you want to set a variable, use a single equals sign. Change `heading.style.color === 'pink'` to `heading.style.color = 'pink'`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong the strict equality (===) and misses a curly brace.

Your code should be:

```
const heading = document.getElementById('Hello')

function addStyleTo(node, text, color, fontSize) {
    node.textContent = text
    node.style.color = color
    node.style.textAlign = 'center' 
    node.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
    node.style.padding = '2rem' 
    node.style.fontSize = fontSize
}

setTimeout(() => {
    addStyleTo(heading, 'Hello', 'red', '3rem')
}, 1000);

heading.onclick = () => {
    if (heading.style.color == 'red') {
        heading.style.color = 'pink' 
    } else {
        heading.style.color = 'red'
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tghcrzum/

Comment: Much appreciated!